# Whatever happened to Perry Rhodan?

Tags: history-of, translation, perry-rhodan

When I was a mere beardless youth back in the 70's, I'd read from my parents' collection of Perry Rhodan stories. The eponymous Major Rhodan was the hero of a very long series of short novels by a gang of uber-prolific German hacks. It was space opera at its most operatic, with humanoid aliens and psionics and wars and you name it. Very pulpy and very fun.

Ace Books was the original American publisher, with the publication and translation organized by the late inimitable [Forry Ackerman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forrest_J_Ackerman). But the American publication stopped at around issue 120 or so. No, seriously, 120. [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perry_Rhodan) they're up to issue 2800 or so in Germany.

My question, which is not entirely clear to me from online searches, **is what is the subsequent US or UK publication history since the 1970's**. Is it possible to find these things in English?

*(I know, it's a separate question as to whether finding them would be worth it. I suspect that my youthful enthusiasm for this German pulp space opera might have been the result of my youth and not the quality of the stories.)*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?27234) lists up to *Perry Rhodan #137*, published in 1979, in the US, and very little in the UK. For English-language publications, ISFDB is usually pretty complete.

Wikipedia mentions a short-lived translation effort in the late 1990s, [in magazine form](http://www.sfsite.com/vault/john38.htm), which [quickly petered out](http://www.perry-rhodan-usa.com/).

No one seems to be actively trying to translate the subsequent stories. So take this as an opportunity to learn German, or at least Spanish, Portuguese, French, Dutch, or perhaps other languages that have more Perry Rhodan translations than English.

Comment: Actually, that's not a bad suggestion at that end there; I do read Spanish, Portuguese, and French so it would be a way to keep my skills up. Thanks!

Comment: Perry Rhodan is published in french in monthly pocket books installments. Each book contains 2 to 3 unit novels from the Rhodan writing team, around 300 pages. Current number is 295.

Answer (score 3):

[PERRY RHODAN enters the English-speaking world](http://www.perry-rhodan.net/newsreader-international/items/perry-rhodan-enters-the-english-speaking-world.html):

> From October 2015 on, these six books will also be published in English – as e-books, translated from German by the American translator Dwight R. Decker. The first volume, published on 8 October, will be »Ark of the Stars« by Frank Borsch (German title: »Die Sternenarche«). We are going to publish the remaining five volumes on a monthly basis.

Answer (score 2):

If you can read German or use Google Translate, the [Perrypedia](http://www.perrypedia.proc.org) has all the information about Perry in the USA [here](http://www.perrypedia.proc.org/wiki/Perry_Rhodan_International#USA) and [here](http://www.perrypedia.proc.org/wiki/Perry_Rhodan_englisch_%28USA%29). The latest number is #2642, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Indications of the Perry Rhodan series in English:
.
http://www.perry-rhodan-usa.com/
.
.
.
Mailing list where many fans can answer questions about the series:
.
http://groups.yahoo.com/group/perryrhodan2/
.

Comment: Both links are dead, which makes this answer worthless.

Answer (score 0):

Perry Rhodan has been translated into English by a group of us up to issue 327 and in the 1800's from 1800 to 1832 and 1851 to 1875. However, they cannot be published because of copyright issues. In Germany they are up to 2934 as of Nov 3, 2017.